# How to design nested template classes where nested classes are of the same type

Tags: c++, class, templates

For my homework assignment, I have to create a linked list and it must be a template class. The assignment calls for one template class called List and another nested template class called Link.

The methods should be defined outside of the class definition.

I created a simple version of the assignment first and it's working, but I feel there is an error in my design.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T1>
class A
{
public:
  template <class T2>
  class B;

  T1    _a;
};

template <class T1>
template <class T2>
class A<T1>::B
{
public:
  T2 _b;
};

int main()
{
  A<int> a;
  a._a = 5;

  A<int>::B<int> b;
  b._b = 10;

  cout << a._a << " " << b._b << "\n";


  return 0;
}
```

My main question is, since the nested class will be of the same type, as you can see from the statement `A<int>::B<int> b;`, is there a way to have class B automatically be of the same type as A? Does my question even make sense? In other words, can I do `A<int>::B b;` and b automatically the same type as A? There will never be a situation where I would have `A<double>::B<int>;` for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, just make `B` not a template. `T1` in `B`'s definition still refers to the template argument of `A`.

```
template <class T1>
class A
{
public:
  class B;

  T1    _a;
}
```

Now, instead of `A<int>::B<int>`, it's simply `A<int>::B`.

`List<int>::Link<double>` wouldn't make sense anyway, so there's no point in it being a template.

Comment: OK, I was thinking that would work, there must have been a problem with my syntax then because I kept getting errors. I will try it again.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why you think you need a template for your inner class.  Have you tried declaring it as a non-template class? e.g.

```
template <class T1>
class A
{
public:
  class B;
private:    
  T1    _a;
};

template <class T1>
class A<T1>::B
{
  T1 _b;
};
```

(Also, while I realise it's just an example, I'd advise against writing classes with **public** data members)

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary, I was just making syntax mistakes I think because I couldn't get the program to compile. I was able to fixit from your sample code. Thanks!